# Query on the meaning of max notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When given, max{a,b}, where a and b are sequences of non negative terms What does this notation mean? I assumed it meant the largest value thats in both sequences however after further reading it asks me to sum this max which means that cant be right.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it means the *sequence* $c_n = \max\{a_n,b_n\}.$  It's the sequence of max's, not the max of sequences.